# redirect if the source traffic comes from twitter

Tags: php

im trying to redirect the traffic that arrives to my website from twitter to another one. i have the next code but is not working.

```
<?php
$referencia = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$referencia = str_replace("http://","", $referencia);
$referencia = str_replace("https://","", $referencia);
$referencia = str_replace("www.","", $referencia);
$peces2 = explode("/", $referencia);

if($referencia == 't.co') {


    $a = 'https://www.anotherwebsite.com';
    $website = $a;

    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: ' . $website);
    exit;
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: You might consider doing this at the web server level rather than the code level.

Comment: have you figured out which part "not work" ? Do you know what $referencia 's value is at each step along the way, for example?

Comment: what isssue are you getting? its working for me

Comment: maybe your `HTTP_REFERER` is empty

Comment: Try logging all your incoming `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` values to be sure you're processing the correct values. From there it's worth writing a function that encapsulates this logic so you can test it with a variety of example cases. You should also [parse the URL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to extract any host or path information instead of relying on regular expressions or really hacky string replacements.

Comment: ok i check $referencia and its ok.. but dont do the redirect so i think the problem is inside de if but i dont see any error there